# mediaqueries max-width not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to use a mediaquerie for max-width. It works fine with Chrome but in Firefox it does not, why?

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/XmGra/1/)

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 400px){    
    .box {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you need a space between and(max-width)

See below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .box {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/XmGra/6/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no closing bracket in your above @media rule -

```
.box{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){

    .box{
        background-color: red;
    }

} /* END THIS @MEDIA RULE */
```

I like to do something really obvious like this to remind me --- 
*You don't need the "and" - or the "screen"*

```
@media (min-width: 30em){ /* ============ */

    body {
        background-color: red;
    }

} /* === END MEDIUM BREAK =============== */
```

Comment: ps - if you are just learning @media rule stuff, I would encourage you to start with min-width only and work from a small screen first mind set.