# Media query (max-width) not work properly in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, media-queries

I have an issue with max-width media query. In this if i am use that media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Then its not work on 480px resolution. But if i am use that media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
}
```

its work with on 480px resolution but not work on 640px. Its work fine with Chrome.

I see this below link also. But not successfull.

[Media queries not work in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100595/media-queries-not-work-in-firefox)

[mediaqueries max-width not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866595/mediaqueries-max-width-not-working-in-firefox)

[Media queries not working on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017777/media-queries-not-working-on-firefox)

My meta tag is:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

Please help.

Comment: getting confused by this and that. how bout redefining the queries as query 1 and query 2?

Comment: do you maybe have another media query that has `min-width: 480px`? This could overwrite the first one at exactly 480px

Comment: can you share your code on `fiddle` or `codepen`

Comment: @Johannes Sir, I have only one media query.

Comment: @Sagar I have only one media query that not work properly. I use second instead of first query.

Comment: Best to give us a jsfiddle or codepen as Super User said so we could identify

Comment: Is there an iFrame in your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Means that changes would occur when screen width gets to `480px` and revert back to normal when screen width gets to `320px`

Don't really know what you want but the explanation above should help you out

Comment: I already use this but that not work with 480px resolution. If i use (max-width: 640px) then it works on 480px resolution but again not work on 640px resolution.

Comment: Do you want it to show on screen size between `320px` and `480px`

Answer (score 0):

It should work perfectly well in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0' name='viewport' />
    <body>
      <div class="change">Some content</div>
    </body>
</html>

.change{
  background: #f00;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  .change{
    background: #0f0;
    color: #00f;
  }
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle example, change the width inside media queries, it should still work.

https://jsfiddle.net/rachit5/xm2tnx53/

> Note that when output is rendered inside an iFrame, the media queries
>   will look for the width of iFrame and not the original page.